# How to return primary key as a response when ever we make a post request using django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I have django model and a view for it define as:

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

queryset = Item.objects.all()
serializer_class = ItemSerializer
```

what should i do to return a primary key as response ? 
This is how my Json looks after making post request:

```
{
        "id": 4,
        "UID": "465666700",
        "name": "rohit ",
        "gender": "MALE",
        "yob": "1996"
    }
```

and my response should be: 4 i.e primary key 
`class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
    class Meta:
    model = Item
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'mrp','imageid', 'company', 'edible','discount','seller_uid','seller_pk')`
```

Help Appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a example JSON with the expected response?

Comment: @arcegk i have added the json and response i want

Comment: @BhupendraSinghChauhan, can you post your current `ItemSerializer` code in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `id` in your `ItemSerializer`, like:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ItemSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(source='pk')
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a ModelSerializer for your Item model. Set the **fields** attribute to ['id'] and that should work!

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model = Item
    fields = ['id']
```